# Prevent ADL on template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I currently have a class template that takes a series of types. Each type may need to be instantiated with the class, itself. What I currently have is something like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct TypeList; // Not defined

struct Placeholder; // Not defined

template <typename Types, typename AnotherType = Default>
class MyClass
{
    // ...
};
```

You can then use it like this:

```
typedef MyClass<TypeList<Container1<Placeholder>, Container2<std::string,
        Placeholder>, OtherType>, OptionalType> MyTypedef;
MyTypedef my_object;
```

`MyClass` will replace appearances of `Placeholder` with itself, use the resulting types, and all is well.

The problem occurs when I try to do something like either of these:

```
MyTypedef *my_ptr = &my_object;
my_free_function(my_object);
```

Both of these cause a compiler error, because the compiler tries to instantiate `Container1<Placeholder>` and `Container2<std::string, Placeholder>` to do argument dependent lookup (ADL), and this instantiation with `Placeholder`, itself, fails.

I know it is possible to avoid ADL by doing, e.g.,

```
MyTypedef *my_ptr = std::addressof(my_object);
(my_free_function)(my_object);
```

However, I don't want to burden the user of `MyClass` with having to constantly suppress ADL. Is there another, straightforward way to have the user provide a list of types without those types being used for ADL?

Comment: At the risk of being obvious, why don't you just define TypeList and Placeholder?

Comment: I am not sure I understand this: *"MyClass will replace appearances of Placeholder with itself, use the resulting types, and all is well."* Can you explain what you mean? How can you replace the placeholder in `MyClass<X<Placeholder>>` with the full type that refers to the placeholder?

Comment: @rici Defining or not defining TypeList doesn't seem to make any difference. The problem with defining Placeholder is to what do I define it? Some templates wouldn't work with an empty struct, and I'd like to avoid having Placeholder mirror the entire interface of MyClass.

Comment: @rkjnsn, I don't actually understand what you're trying to do, but I don't see how a template that won't "work with an empty struct" will "work with an incomplete type". Mind you, I don't know what you mean by "work" in this context either.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas MyClass basically does `typedef typename SubstituteType<Types, Placeholder, MyClass>::type InternalTypeList`, where SubstituteType does what it says on the tin.

Comment: @rici Given this class: `template <typename T> class Example {typedef std::pair<int, typename T::TestType> Pair; Pair *pair;};`, where TestType is a typedef in MyClass, `MyClass<TypeList<Example<Placeholder> > > test;` compiles, but `&test` does not.

Comment: @rici That is, even with Placeholder defined as an empty struct.

Comment: rkjnsn: without seeing the implementation of SubstituteType, it's hard to be sure, but it seems to me that MyClass cannot be complete if it uses the TypeList for anything. But I've been surprised by C++ templates before, so I'm prepared to be surprised again.

Comment: You can work it around by just forward declaring the `Container1` and `Container2` class templates. The compiler won't try to instantiate them, then.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Unfortunately, they have to be defined, because MyClass needs to use them after it does type substitution on the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got everything working. The trick was to use a dependent type instead of using a template, directly. My final solution was to define TypeList as follows:

```
template <typename... Types>
struct TypeList
{
private:
    struct Holder
    {
    private:
        typedef TypeList<Types...> InnerTypeList;
        template <typename Types, typename AnotherType>
        friend class MyClass;
    };
public:
    typedef Holder type;
};
```

Then, the users of MyClass can do

```
typedef MyClass<TypeList<Container1<Placeholder>, Container2<std::string,
        Placeholder>::type, OtherType>, OptionalType> MyTypedef;
MyTypedef my_object;
```

Note the addition of '::type'

Finally, in MyClass, I replaced

```
typedef typename SubstituteType<Types, Placeholder, MyClass>::type InternalTypeList;
```

with

```
typedef typename SubstituteType<Types::InnerTypeList, Placeholder, MyClass>::type
        InternalTypeList;
```

giving me the same type for `InternalTypeList` as before.

Because the dependent type `Holder` has no template parameters of it's own, the compiler doesn't have to instantiate the Placeholder types for ADL purposes, and everything works properly.